# rspec create() method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am working on an online learning portal like [bento](https://bento.io/). For a user to unlock the next lesson, they must have to review at least one submission from the other user on the assignment of any previous lessons(complete by the current user). Considering this logic, I have a rspec test where I have tested if the page is being redirected to the other user's submission or not? In order to pass the test, I have to create dummy submission. For that, I am using create() method but the redirection to submission page is failing on the test but it works fine on the website. The code responsible for redirection in submission_controller is

```
def review_submission
 @submission = Submission.where('lesson_id < ?', current_user.submissions.last.assignment.lesson_id.to_i)
                        .shuffle[1]
 if @submission.nil?
  redirect_to @assignment
 else
  redirect_to assignment_submission_path(assignment_id: @assignment.id, id: @submission.id)
 end
end
```

The code of the test is

```
it "redirects to submission path" do
    admin_user = create(:admin_user)
    sign_in admin_user
    user = create(:user)
    sign_in user
    assignment = create(:assignment, admin_user_id: admin_user.id)
    #I was creating dummy submissions data using rspec create method.
    submission = create(:submission, lesson_id: 1) 
    post :create, params: { submission: attributes_for(:submission, user_id: user.id), assignment_id: assignment.id}

    expect(response).to redirect_to assignment_submission_path( assignment_id: assignment.id, id: Submission.last.id)
  end
```

Dummy data is coming from FactoryGirl

```
factory :submission do
  user_id 1
  assignment_id 1
  lesson_id 2
  content "this is the submission of my assignment"
  factory :invalid_submission do
    content ""
  end
end
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what error you get

Comment: `1) SubmissionsController POST #create When attributes are valid redirects to submission path
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to assignment_submission_path( assignment_id: assignment.id, id: Submission.last.id)
     
       Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/assignments/20/submissions/21> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/assignments/20>.
       Expected "http://test.host/assignments/20/submissions/21" to be === "http://test.host/assignments/20".`

Comment: @RabinGaire seems like your rspec is testing for controller-action: submissions#create, please update your question and show your `submissions_controller#create` code. You don't really need to actually show the code for `review_submission`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `@submission` is nil, so it's redirecting you to the `Attachments#show` page instead of the `Submissions#show page`. You're setting it like:

```
@submission = Submission.where('lesson_id < ?', current_user.submissions.last.assignment.lesson_id.to_i).shuffle[1]
```

It's trying to find the Submission based on `current_user.submissions`. Your Factory is just making the submission like:

```
submission = create(:submission, lesson_id: 1)
```

That defaults the `user_id` to be `1`, which probably isn't the ID of your signed in user (since you create the admin user above it). Try passing in the `user_id` to your FactoryGirl's creation of the Submission. May also want to pass in the `assignment_id` too actually, so the Submission will correctly belong to the Assignment.

```
submission = create(:submission, lesson_id: 1, user_id: user.id, assignment_id: assignment.id)
```

Then the Submission should be assigned to your User, and hopefully the Controller will find it and your test will pass.